# Using jQuery selector for class plus another attribute

Tags: jquery, selector

What I am wanting to do is add a class to a specific element with a specific url. But I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have.

```
var pageName = window.location.pathname
    pageName = pageName.replace("/", "");

$("div.mainleftmenu a.rtsLink.rtsRoot[href=pageName]").addclass("rtsSelected");
```

If it helps a.rtsLink.rtsRoot is several steps into the hierarchy. I'm new to jQuery.

### Update

Thanks for the quick response, but I am still getting an error.

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addclass' [http://XXXXXXX/training-events:69]

Here is a sample of the markup I am trying to traverse. (And this is auto-generated so modifying the html is not an option.)

```
<div class="mainleftmenu">                       
    <div id="mainleftmenu_T76A8AA8B013">
        <div id="ctl00_mainleftmenu_T76A8AA8B013_ctl00_ctl00_siteMapControl_verticalsimple"
        class="RadTabStripVertical RadTabStrip_mainleftmenu RadTabStripLeft_mainleftmenu">
            <div class="rtsLevel rtsLevel1">
                <ul class="rtsUL">
                    <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst">
                        <a class="rtsLink rtsRoot" href="products">
                            <span class="rtsOut">
                                <span class="rtsIn">
                                    <span class="rtsTxt">Products</span>
                                </span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rtsLI">
                        <a class="rtsLink" href="products/heavybid">
                            <span class="rtsOut">
                                 <span class="rtsIn">
                                    <span class="rtsTxt">HeavyBid</span>
                                </span>
                             </span>
                         </a>
                   </li>
                </ul>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the variable to the selector, currently you are passing a string:

```
$("div.mainleftmenu a.rtsLink.rtsRoot[href='"+pageName+"']").addClass("rtsSelected");
```

Also please note that you have written `addclass` which should be `addClass`.

Answer (score 1):

This should make it so that you don't use the string `pageName`, but you use the value of `pageName`:

```
$("div.mainleftmenu a.rtsLink.rtsRoot[href='"+pageName+"']")
                                               .addClass("rtsSelected");
```