# jquery finding an element with known class and value

Tags: jquery, indexing, element

im trying to get an element using jquery who has a certain class and also a specific value which only one of the elements who have that class have.
for example

```
<div class="asd" value="a"></div>
```

out of :

```
<div class="asd"></div>
<div class="asd"></div>
<div class="asd"></div>
<div class="asd"></div>
```

so far i tried something like : `$(".mainCss[value=yay]").index()`
yay is a string object.

Comment: Please post exactly what you tried. From what I can tell, the code you posted should find anything which a value of "yay"

Comment: *"yay is a string object"* What does that mean? Do you mean that `yay` is a variable and you want to use the variable's value in the selector?

Comment: Your example div's clearly have a class of "asd" which means you need to use $(".asd") at least to select elements of that class, then you can worry about the value (see answers below).

Comment: @zsawyer I assume that was a copy+paste error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery Selector for class plus another attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836498/using-jquery-selector-for-class-plus-another-attribute)

Comment: JavaScript does not do string interpolation. It does not know that you want `yay` inside the string to refer to the variable `yay`. You have to use *string concatenation*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/String_Operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not what you think it is. You seem to be confused about how to put a string object inside a selector. What you intended is (probably) this:

```
$(".mainCss[value='"+yay+"']").index()
```

which will put the value of the variable `yay` into the selector. If this variable is unconstrained, you should escape it too.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".mainCss[value='yay']").index()
```

you need to surround the value with single quotes.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/: "Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string"

Comment: even if its a string object? @Prog_Mania

Comment: what do u mean with object ? @OriGavrielRefael

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael yes works with strings, actually it deals it as string. but you have to swap the use of ' and " in the selector.

Comment: @Prog: `'.mainCss[value="yay"]'` would still treat `yay` literally and not interpret it as variable. I don't understand the point of your last comment.

Comment: @FelixKling that wasn't the question, he's asking if you can use either " for string or '.

Comment: in the second comment, even if its a string object?

Comment: I don't see how you interpret this as a question about which quotation marks to use. As you can see in the fourth comment, after you asked to clarify his statement, he says he has a variable `yay`: `var yay = "asd"`. So I assume he wants to use the value of that variable in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mainCss[value='a']").index()
```

is more spefically what you wanted to select the div in the question  you have the code right though